# How to serialize request.user for ModelSerializer to auto fill the user field in Model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This question is not good question but, I spent 6 hours to solve this problem, searching in stackoverflow and still problem is bother me.
I have a model as below :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=144)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

and its serializer :

```
class ProductSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ["user"]
```

and my view is like below :

```
class CreateProduct(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """"""
    serializer_class = [ProductSerailizer]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return self.serializer(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer.save()
        return response.Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I wanna auto fill the user by the request, but when I send the request with postman it says :

> "username": [
> "A user with that username already exists."
> ]

and it doesn't save my instance.
I don't know how to handle this.
I wanna type this with generics.
Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: You use a `UserSerializer` in the `post`, not the `ProductSrializer`?

Comment: oh ... i see it  by now

Comment: thanks bro ... I am so tired. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to willeM_ Van Onsem
I made a mistake in post function. I use UserSerializer instead of ProductSerializer
thanks man.

```
class CreateProduct(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """"""
    serializer_class = [ProductSerailizer]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return self.serializer(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_serializer = ProductSerailizer(data=request.data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer.save()
        return response.Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is one is right.